# Is it worth allowing us to upload images to the comments?

Tags: feature-request, comments, images

If we need to show a screenshot (pertaining to error messages for example) in comments, what should we do? Is it worth allowing us to upload images to the comments?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Comments are supposed to be small remarks on question and answers -- they feature a limitation of 600 characters. If you feel the need to add a screenshot to a comment, you a) are in all likelihood the person who asked the original question b) should edit your question to include the additional information (and the screenshot). If you are *not* the questioner and by all means need to add a screenshot, ask a new (follow-up) question with a link to the original one.

Answer (score 9):

There were a few instances where I did use the "Ask Question" page to upload an image that I then linked to in a comment, using the markdown syntax `[this is some text](http://address-of-comment)`. But in general I agree with what lockstep says.